# How to convert a string containing a byte string to a byte string

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

How do I convert a string which contains the literal representation of a byte string, to a byte string?

This might seem strange, but for a library I'm using for a certain type of exception I need one of the attributes of the exception, this gives me the value I need, but it is a byte string in a string.

It is `"value=b'\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'"`, I can get the value by splitting on the equals and then using `eval`, such as

```py
>>> eval("value=b'\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'".split("=")[1])
     
b'\xbbOFa\x14\xdb{\xf5\x1b~H\xba\x96\xdaec'
```

This works, but as we all know `eval` can be very, very bad. So, is there an alternative to using `eval`?

Comment: Python 2.4 had a "string_escape" encoder https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: You should not be using eval here, so I unduplicated

Comment: @mkrieger. I've re-opened the question. I don't believe that this is really about eval. eval is just a crutch being used as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `unicode-escape` codec that will convert bytes containing literal sequences like `\x..` or `\u....` into their equivalent characters in the string. The remainder of the string is converted using the `latin1` encoding, which just translates all the bytes.

So you convert the string to raw bytes using `latin1`, then convert back to a string using `unicode-escape`, and finally back to bytes using `latin1` again:

```
>>> s = '\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1')
b'\xbbOFa\x14\xdb{\xf5\x1b~H\xba\x96\xdaec'
```

Getting rid of the clutter around the string is pretty easy using regex or the more manual parsing you showed. For example:

```
>>> x = "value=b'\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'"
>>> s = re.fullmatch('[^\'"]+b([\'"])(.*)\\1[^\'"]*', x).group(2)
>>> s
'\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'
```

OR

```
>>> s = x.split('=')[1].lstrip('b').strip("'")
>>> s
'\\xbbOFa\\x14\\xdb{\\xf5\\x1b~H\\xba\\x96\\xdaec'
```